# How IDE releases resources?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, resources, intellij-idea

All modern IDE has possibility to run some piece of code when you stay in debug. Intellij Idea has "Watches" window, Eclipse has "Expressions" window. It is interesting how resources is cleaned if I make a call like that (conenction variable is java.sql.Connection):

```
connection.prepareCall("some sql function");
```

This produce a CallableStatment, may be several times, but when it/they will be closed? Or this CallableStatment will exist forever?

Answer (score 0):

If the IDE is written in Java, it will behave like any other Java object: once it no longer has a reference attached (such as by being output to a console but not having a reference saved anywhere), it's eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: You told about POJO. What about if such "object" depends on external resource? For example you can not wait until GC destroy ResultSet, because database resource associated with it will exist. That is the problem.

Comment: Unless you hold on to the resource and release it manually, you'll leak, just like any other use of externally-allocated resources in Java. If the object has a finalizer, that may release the resources, but as finalizer execution isn't guaranteed, you may leak the resource anyway.